# How do you draw more current from a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, led, current, watts

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I can't find it anywhere. I was watching a video that described how one can calculate the power of something with this equation: voltage x current = power.

This is the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSpB3HivkhY&ab_channel=Afrotechmods

[image]

The picture shows that you can get the same power for the light even though one receives a 120 volt power supply while the other from a 12 volt power supply. The difference is the current.

I'm wondering how do you control to get the right amount of current? How come the light bulb on the left doesn't get 3.33A instead of 0.333A, for example?

Comment: Common misconception when starting out in electronics  - That the SOURCE is what controls the driven current.  It doesn't.  It has some maximum that it can reach, but aside from that special case, the amount of current driven is actually controlled by the LOAD.   It's like using the water faucet in your house.  There's some PSI pressure the water has in the pipes.   If you open the valve fully, you get "maximum current' (maximum water flow).  But you can reduce that by simply closing the valve.  Clearly the valve (load) is what controls the water flow, not the source of the water pressure.

Comment: @KyleB, Re, "the SOURCE...doesn't." You assume that the source is a constant-voltage power supply. That's reasonable since most power supplies _are_ constant voltage, but the OP deserves to know that that's not the only possibility. If you drive that LED module with a constant current supply, then the power supply will control the current, and the load will determine the voltage.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  Good point.   He did say "12V supply"   FWIW.   TY for keeping me honest  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You use a load with a different equivalent resistance.

> How come the light bulb on the left doesn't get 3.33A instead of 0.333A, for example?

Because this light bulb has about 360 ohms resistance, not 36 ohms.

In the case of the LED bulb, it's a little more complicated and the device can't be characterized with a single resistance value. But just the same, this part draws 3.33 A because it's designed to draw 3.33 A at 12 V, rather than 0.33 A or 33.3 A.

Comment: Guess what? The light bulb on the left DOES GET 3.33A, when its filament is cool. its resistance increases 10 times when the filament is at 2000 degrees C. The high temperature is a terrific waste of power.  The LED will produce much less heat and almost 5 times more light.